# Ruby string to_f... bug?

Tags: ruby

```
"9.99".to_f
=> 999.0
```

Is this the expected behavior?  How would one convert "9.99" to 9.99

Comment: This looks like it may be a Ruby Enterprise Edition bug

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/emm-ruby/browse_thread/thread/d327b07bbcb1351c

Comment: Ouch. Out of curiosity, does this cause a failure for rubyspec?

Answer (score 3):

What locale are you running in? My *guess* is that it's treating "." as a thousands separator (which happens to be in the wrong place in this case) and "," as a decimal point.

Try

```
"9,99".to_f
```

... but if that works, it's probably dependent on the current culture of the system, and you should look to find a culture-invariant way of converting.

Comment: @Chirantan: The question is what it does on the OP's computer. That will help to detect whether it's a culture-related issue.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Ruby are you using ?

"9.99".to_f results in 9.99 for me using Ruby 1.8.6 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

What version? This works as expected on 1.8.7.

```
irb(main):001:0> "9.99".to_f
=> 9.99
```

.

```
ruby -e "puts \"9.99\".to_f"
9.99
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some nasty gem or a Rails plugin changed your String#to_f behaviour...

Answer (score -1):

Sure. It's a culture dependent conversion. Tested on IronRuby 0.9